# Fetch data using $http for use with a custom service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a custom service which pulls the list of all defined statuses from the server for use in forms, so far I have:

```
SimpleTaskApp.factory('storyStatus', function($http) {
    var data = null;
    var promise = $http({
            url: '/story-status/',
            method: 'GET'
        }).success(function (resp) {
            data = resp;
        });
    return {list: data }};
});
```

I understand this won't work since $http is asynchronous, however I have no desire to run the request more than once. I'd like to treat it as a static variable in effect, so if ever storyStatus.list is called, it should check whether it is empty and then attempt to populate itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should work *with* promises instead of against them.

You don't need to store the data because you can store the *promise*. The point of promises is that you don't know when they'll be done. You don't know when your data will be available.

So your service **must** return the promise. But that's okay:

```js
SimpleTaskApp.factory('storyStatus', function($http) {
  var promise;

  function getData() {
    if ( ! angular.isDefined( promise ) ) {
      promise = $http({
        url: '/story-status/',
        method: 'GET'
      });
    }

    return promise;
  }

  return { list: getData };
});
```

In this service, your `$http` call will only be called once, but will return a promise whenever you call `SimpleTaskApp.list()`. Your controller that calls it doesn't need to know if the data is there yet because it will react the same regardless, e.g.:

```js
SimpleTaskApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, storyStatus) {
  storyStatus.list().then(function( data ) {
    $scope.statuses = data.statuses;
  });
});
```

If the data is already retrieved, the `then` will run basically immediately; if not, it will run when the data gets back. The controller doesn't need to know anything about the internal state of the `storyStatus` service.

So promises not only help with asynchronous tasks, but they also help keep our components decoupled, which is a big deal in AngularJS - and should be in other frameworks too!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this maybe?

```
SimpleTaskApp.factory('storyStatus', function($http) {

    var promise = $http({
        url: '/story-status/',
        method: 'GET'
    });

    return { list: promise };
});
```

Calling code

```
storyStatus.list.then(function (data) {
});
```

You might want to consider using a `synchronous` ajax call to simplify your API if you are only loading the list once.